# Div has class but its properties do not show up in the inspector

Tags: css, sass

This is one of the most weird things I have encountered in CSS.

I have a class named .thin with the following properties:

```
.thin {
    width: 75% !important;
}
```

I also have a class named .themered with these properties:

```
.themered {
    background: $themeRed !important;
    border-color: darken($themeRed, 15%) !important;
}
```

Then I have a DIV with both of those classes, but neither shows up in the inspector and it does not have any of their properties.

This is a screencap of the DIV in question:

[image]

As you can see, the class names are not even listed in the inspector.

... and to make it even more weird, here is another DIV that has the class .thin and .themered - and it works just as it supposed to do.

[image]

I have literally tried everything. Have you had to deal with anything similar before?

Comment: Have you written CSS in same page or different file?

Comment: This is a SASS file, and it is in a file of its own.

Comment: I had something like this in WordPress. The problem was in the cache after changes in CSS I had to clear all browser cache to see those changes.

Comment: Yeah clear full cache or check page in private browser

Comment: Are you sure you do not have another class wrapping your `.thin` declaration?

Comment: If you look at the attached screencaps it seems as if the browser interprets the class names "themered" and "thin" as a SINGULAR class name with a space in between "thin themered" - and there is of course no such class.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out what the hell was happening by accident.

There was an unwanted hidden symbol in between the tags that dynamically created the class names, resulting in the browser thinking that the two distinct class names where actually a single class name with some weird "A" symbol in between.

You can check the following screencap. It's an error message I got by messing around, and as you can see there is a symbol between the {{theme}} and {{class}}:

[Error message with hidden symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X3Wy.png)

Thanks for the help everyone.